# React-Native Wix Navigation v2 Building Proper Flow

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm very new at Wix Navigation, I do really like the feeling of native in navigating but its also very hard.. I cant understand how I should build.
I want to be able to start my app with single welcome screen, then I will navigate the user to login/register screens. After they login they will be inside of home page, and home page will have sideMenu. I have created the home page with side menus but I cant make welcome screen show up before, something fails anyways..

I really tried so many combinations but I cant make it properly, can someone give me a small example how I would do that? Here actually welcome screen shows up first but it have backbutton, which I dont want.. when I press back button it goes to home page, instead we should be able to go to home page from welcome

Wanted flow: Welcome -> Login -> Home(with side menus)

```
Navigation.registerComponent(`WelcomeScreen`, () => Welcome);
    Navigation.registerComponent(`HomeScreen`, () => Home);
    Navigation.registerComponent(`Screen2`, () => Screen2);

    Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {

        Navigation.setRoot({
            root: {
                sideMenu: {
                left: {
                    component: {
                        name: 'Screen2',
                        passProps: {
                            text: 'This is a left side menu screen'
                        },
                    },
                },
                center: {
                    stack: {
                        children:[
                            {
                                component: {
                                    name: 'HomeScreen',
                                    options:{
                                        topBar:{
                                            visible: true,
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'Home',
                                                color: 'red',
                                                alignment: 'center'
                                            },
                                        },
                                    }
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                component:{
                                    name: 'WelcomeScreen',
                                    options:{
                                        topBar:{
                                            visible: true,
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'Welcome',
                                                color: 'red',
                                                alignment: 'center'
                                            },
                                        },
                                    }
                                },
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                right: {
                    component: {
                        name: 'Screen2',
                        passProps: {
                            text: 'This is a right side menu screen'
                        }
                    }
                },


                options: {
                    sideMenu: {
                        left: {
                            width: 250*SW,
                        },
                    },
                }
            },
        },

        })

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by putting the welcome screen as your root and then pushing the login screen on top of that and if the user is logged in setting the root again by putting the above code in setRoot. [Example](https://github.com/dabit3/react-native-navigation-v2/tree/Part2)

Edit

index.js :

```
Navigation.events ().registerAppLaunchedListener (() => {
Navigation.setRoot ({
root: {
  stack: {
    children: [
      {
        component: {
          id: 'WelcomeScreen', // Optional, Auto generated if empty
          name: 'navigation.playground.WelcomeScreen', // WelcomeScreen Id
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  },
 });
});
```

push to HomeScreen.js

ScreenOne.js :

```
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';

static propTypes = {
  componentId: PropTypes.string,
};

pushScreen () {
   Navigation.push (this.props.componentId, {
     component: {
       name: 'navigation.playground.HomeScreen' // HomeScreen.js Id
    },
  });
}
```

Try if this pushing screen logic works for you

Comment: yeah you are right, i think same but, strange thing push is not working when I do like that.. and if you have tried it as you meant, can you write a full example for that so i can try it and tell you if it works.